# Change the direction of ag-grid to RTL

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid in react, and I want to change the direction to RTL, also use of local text. Based on the ag-grid documentation `enableRtl={true}` would change the style of the grid. It is true when we set it permanently, but when I want to change it programmatically, it does not change. I passed the variable through props to the component for changing the direction and translating the text. This is my code

```
 const Grid= ({dir}) =>{
  return (
    <div 
      className="ag-theme-balham"
      style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }} 
    >
      <AgGridReact
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        columnDefs={column}
        rowData={rowData}
        enableRtl={dir === 'rtl'}
        localeTextFunc={(key, defaultValue) => {
          return dir === 'rtl' ? gridLocal[key] : defaultValue; 
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[before changing direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAtGY.jpg)

[after changing direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRNnw.jpg)

[As it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBC08.jpg)

I searched for the solution, but I cannot find a way to solve it. 
What should I do? What is wrong with my code?

Edit: where I used the Grid component

```
const MainLayout = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => { setOpen(true) };
  const handleDrawerClose = () => { setOpen(false) };

  return (
    <div >
      <Topbar 
        setLang={props.setLang}
        drawerOpen={handleDrawerOpen} 
        drawerClose={handleDrawerClose} 
        status={open}
        handleSignOut={props.handleSignOut}
      />
      <div style={{height:'48px'}}/>
      <div className={classes.content}>
        <Sidebar open={open} drawerClose={handleDrawerClose}/> 
        <Grid dir={theme.direction}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try doing `dir == 'rtl'` or `dir==="rtl"` as triple equals checks for type with comparision so both the values should have same type.

Comment: No difference, I think the issue is related to the rendering of the grid

Comment: Debug and see what value is being passed to dir

Comment: I checked it with the React DevTools and console.log, and the value is correct.

Comment: How could I rerender the grid when the variable is changed?
@SameerRezaKhan

Comment: The component should re render if you are using statefull component. Can you add code of component where Grid is used

Comment: I add the code where the Grid is used to the question

Comment: It seems the ag-grid cached the variable. If I go to another component and back to the one that the Grid is used, the direction has applied.
@SameerRezaKhan

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. After searching many times, I found only one solution.
I used angular not react, but, I can tell you the steps I used to solve this problem.

I followed the following steps:

1. I stored the value of the direction in the localstorage
2. Created a button to trigger an event that will change the value of the direction.
3. Get the value of the direction from the localstorage in the constructor
4. Inside the trigger, I changed the value on the localstorage for each click event.
5. finally, at each click event refresh the page with `window.location.reload()` to see the effect.

I know. It is not the perfect solution, but this is the only solution that worked for me. I think this problem is not found in the enterprise version of ag-grid.

**Update:**
I found a better solution. I use angular not React.
In angular, I used `<ng-template>` as follow:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="AgGridDir === 'rtl'" [ngIfElse]="LeftGrid" #Withbutton>
          <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 450px;"
            [class]="Table_Color_mode===Constants.light || Theme_dir===Constants.light?'ag-theme-alpine':'ag-theme-alpine-dark'"
            [rowData]="ItemsMainCategories | async" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" (gridReady)="OnGridReady($event)"
            [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate" [animateRows]="true"
            [enableRtl]="true" [frameworkComponents]="agFrameworks" rowSelection="single"
            (rowEditingStarted)="onRowEditingStarted($event)" (cellValueChanged)="UpdateItemMainCat($event)">
          </ag-grid-angular>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #LeftGrid>
          <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 450px;"
            
            [class]="Table_Color_mode===Constants.light || Theme_dir===Constants.light?'ag-theme-alpine':'ag-theme-alpine-dark'"
            [rowData]="ItemsMainCategories | async" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" (gridReady)="OnGridReady($event)"
            [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate" [animateRows]="true"
            [enableRtl]="false" [frameworkComponents]="agFrameworks" rowSelection="single"
            (rowEditingStarted)="onRowEditingStarted($event)" (cellValueChanged)="UpdateItemMainCat($event)">
          </ag-grid-angular>
        </ng-template>
```

`<ng-template>` is a tag created by Angular framework that can be used to render some components or HTML tags based on a condition.

As you can see, I used the same Ag-grid table with the same parameters. Each one with an `ng-template`. I used a variable called `AgGridDir` which is dynamically changed to `rtl` to `ltr` based on the user choice.

If the user chooses 'rtl' the first template is rendered and the `[enableRtl]="true"` is set to true, and if the user chooses 'ltr', then the second template will be rendered dynamically without reloading the page and the `[enableRtl]="false"`.

I don't know about react much details, but, I want to share the idea.